# I'm having an issue tying to deploy app on heroku. Erro Code h10

Tags: node.js, heroku

Thanks in advance. I'm a beginner, apologies if this question is ridiculous.

I have a Procfile and it seems like that should be working.

I tried adding

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js"
}
```

to my package.json.

My heroku logs read as follows:

```
2020-05-01T20:22:43.838621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-anchorage-20795.herokuapp.com request_id=b5aebc83-44db-482e-9f57-543a84aadb90 fwd="162.84.137.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-01T20:22:45.166890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-anchorage-20795.herokuapp.com request_id=7d65b439-4dd1-4c5f-ac2e-89ee3bae74f5 fwd="162.84.137.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The code is hosted here:

https://github.com/DaleLuce/newsletter-signup

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my procfile, before it was

```
web:node app.js
```

I added a space......

```
web: node app.js
```

Aaaaand it worked.